# Scaling PHP message server in Google App Engine

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine, scalability

I have built out a chat application that allows it to "save" these messages by pushing them to my server/db, built in PHP and MySQL.

The setup of my present PHP server accepts the request and directs it to the proper case statment given the defined `action` passed into the request as:

```
<?php

switch($action) 
{

    case "userLogin": 
        ...
    break;  


    case "signUpUser":
        ...
    break;  

        ...

    case "syncWithServer":
        ...
    break;  

?>
```

where each case statement allows for database insert and update and subsequent return upon the actions success given the data passed.

For a detailed example, we have the `sendMessage` case below. The data must be inserted and then return the latest sync_id, for that message just inserted, then sent back to the user so as to keep everything in sync:

```
case "sendMessage":

    // Output is: {"message_sync_id":"4"}
    if ($userId = authenticateUser($db, $username, $password, $gcmregid)) 
    {   
        //echo "passed1";
        if (isset($_REQUEST['to_user_sync_id']))
        {
            //echo "passed2";a
             $touserid = $_REQUEST['to_user_sync_id'];               
             $unescapedMessage = $_REQUEST['message_text'];
             $message = mysql_real_escape_string($unescapedMessage);             
             $campaign = $_REQUEST['shared_campaign_id'];
             $location = $_REQUEST['shared_campaign_location_id'];

             if($stmt1 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `messages` (`message_sync_id`,`from_user_sync_id`, `to_user_sync_id`, sent_dt, `message_text`,`shared_campaign_id`,`shared_campaign_location_id`) 
                                      SELECT 
                                      CASE 
                                      WHEN max(message_sync_id) is null
                                      THEN 0
                                      ELSE max(message_sync_id)
                                      END + 1
                                      , ?
                                      , ?
                                      , NOW()
                                      , ?
                                      , ?
                                      , ?
                                      from messages;"))
             {
                $stmt1->bind_param("sssss", $userId,$touserid,$message,$campaign,$location);
                $stmt1->execute();
                $stmt1->close();

                $sqlMaxSyncId = "select max(message_sync_id) as message_sync_id from messages;";

                if($resultMaxID = $db->query($sqlMaxSyncId))
                {

                    $row = $resultMaxID->fetch_assoc();

                    $out = json_encode(array('message_sync_id' => $row['message_sync_id']));

                    error_log("sendMessage", 3 , $row['message_sync_id']);

                }
                else
                {
                    $out = FAILED;
                }           

             }
             else
             {
                $out = FAILED;
             }

        }
        else
        {
            $out = FAILED;
        }   
    }
    else
    {
        $out = FAILED;
    }   
break;
```

If this is launched on the Google App Engine, will there be issues if it scales to several million request per day?

Will latency be affected?

If so, how can I alleviate?

Comment: Your latency will be caused by the Database. MySQL is a strongly consistent database, which means it will definitely slow down the more requests you throw at it. You can try out Google Cloud Datastore, which was specifically built to scale automagically like App Engine.

If you are building a real-time chat application, I would highly recommend checking out Firebase. https://firechat.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: In your opinion how far do you think Google Cloud data store will take me in terms of number of requests?  several million, tens of millions before hitting any kind of serious latency issue?

Comment: Cloud Datastore will not work with SQL, you will have to rewrite your app a bit. If you set up your data structure correctly, datastore should not run into latency issues even with millions of requests. I need to know more about your app to recommend a good data structure. However, I would REALLY recommend Firebase.

Comment: The server itself is really simple as I demonstrated. it's really just storage while the real chatting is handled by pubnub to ensure that the messages get to and from each respective user. However to ensure that everything is synced correctly I have the insert and then subsequent retrieval of the max sync ID over the entry that was just inserted to ensure that when they refresh their data everything will be synced correctly.

Comment: I'm not simply using the server for Chat, but also friend relationships and allowing creating and saving events as well

Comment: @SandeepDinesh Have you built apps with Firebase?

Comment: I have built many apps with both App Engine and Firebase. You can easily build just the chat portion in firebase and the rest with App Engine and MySQL. As you get more and more messages, finding the max sync_id will slow to a crawl, especially once you get a lot of traffic! Another option is to shard your mysql database, which will allow you to scale, but this is not easy. I've never set up a sharded MySQL with App Engine though.

Comment: @SandeepDinesh ok, thank you. What I am thinking now is to simply keep the friend relationships within MySQL (the explicit social side), but allow everything else in Firebase and get rid of this sync_id logic. The real appeal of Firebase is the syncing anyway, so my logic is redundant, also given once you are friends with a person, that relationship is rarely changed

Comment: Thank you,  thank you,  thank you,  for the note on firebase, I've spent the weekend rebuilding the backend and it is so much more elegant and simple and straightforward than dealing with what I had originally configured!!

Comment: I think that's a pretty good architecture! Glad it worked out :)